# What is the effect of passing exports to an anonymous function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was looking at the code for the [node-etherdream](https://github.com/possan/node-etherdream/blob/master/etherdream.js) library and in the main module I saw this:

(abbreviated):

```
(function(ns) {
   /// a bunch of code

})(exports);
```

I have never seen `exports` being passed into an anonymous function like this, nor do I see `module.exports` anywhere in this code.  Yet, this file is being `reuire`d like any other module.

Can someone explain this use of `exports` to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exports is special object that you can set variables into.
So in this example when the function executes it passes this object exports.

If you want to export some variable you can set it in ns variable(exports) in this case like that:

```
(function(ns) {
/// a bunch of code
    ns.func1 = function(){}

    ns.func2 = function(){}

    ns.age = 20
})(exports);
```

When you require the file from other file you will get access to this variables func1, func2 and age like that:

```
var o = require('file.js')
o.func1();
o.func2();
o.age // => 20
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the below `Immediately Invoked Function Expression (IIFE)` (*pronounced* `iffy`) where `exports` is passed as argument to the function's `ns` argument below.

```
(function(ns) {
   /// a bunch of code

})(exports);
```

When you look inside the code `EtherDream` object is getting created with all the methods required and finally bound to the `ns` argument where `ns` is getting passed as `exports` and the below line is equivalent to `exports.EtherDream = EtherDream;`

```
(function(ns) {
   /// a bunch of code


   ns.EtherDream = EtherDream;

})(exports);
```

If you are still not understanding how `IIFE` works and its arguments, you can execute the sample `iife` snippet below.

```js
(function(ns) {
       console.log(ns);
       
})(10); // argument passed as 10 to ns


// This is same as below global scope method

function another(ns) {
  console.log(ns);
}

another(10);
```